# Type ´Any´ has no subscript members

Tags: swift

I have working json parsing code for swift2.2 but when i use it for Swift 3.0 I get errors (Type ´Any´ has no subscript members), can anyone please help me convert the code.

```
do {        
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)

                if json is [String: AnyObject] {
                    print(json)

                    if let error = json["error"] as? String {
                        print(error);
                    } else if let items = json["items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                        for item in items {
                            print(item)

                            let book_id = item["id"] as? String

                            if let volumeInfo = item["volumeInfo"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                let book_title = volumeInfo["title"] as? String
                                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                                    self.lblDataInfo.text = "ISBN: "+self.currentISBN!+"  ID:"+book_id!
                                    self.lblDataType.text = book_title
                                })
                            }

                            break // for now, only show first
                        }

                    } else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                            self.lblDataInfo.text = "ISBN: "+self.currentISBN!+"  Not identified"
                            self.lblDataType.text = ""
                        })
                    }
                }

            } catch let jsonError {
                print(jsonError)
            }

            }
            task.resume()

        }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of related questions in the **Related** column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:  `if json is [String: AnyObject] {` is checking if json is a dictionary, but doesn't cast it to a dictionary, so when you try and access it as a dictionary here: `json["error"]` you're trying to access it as a dictionary.

Instead, you just need to cast it to a new variable with the correct type:

`if let jsonDictionary = json as? [String : AnyObject] {`

Answer (score -1):

It seems as though the json data comes through but it does not know what type the data is, because as of now it is of type `Any`

```
if json is [String: AnyObject] {
                print(json)
let jsonData = json as! NSDictionary // or if you want to be more specific ,'json as! [String: AnyObject]' but u will have to cast the value of your dict 'AnyObject' later on
```

now, the data is not of type 'Any' but of type 'NSDictionary'

If you want to test it out you can put a breakpoint by the `print(json)` line and after you run the code, in the console type in `po json as! NSDictionary` so you can see if NSDictionary is the right type to cast your json data